# android integer text as ressource

Tags: android, reference, integer

is it possible to avoid storing images in a database and putting them into the drawable or mipmap folders instead? In the database then I would like to put only the reference to ressources and call it like this:

```
String image = "R.mipmap.image1";        //This will be the data retrieved from Database
int imageInt = Integer.parseInt(image);
imgview.setImageRessource(imageInt);
```

Actually I want to use this in a RecyclerView so I simplified the example code here but this is showing me the following error

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.mipmap.image1"

Thanks

Comment: search on google for convert string to drawable than after post your exact problem here

Comment: `mipmap` is not the correct place where to store your graphic resource. Only the app icon must reside in the `mipmap` folder(s). And yes, you can retrieve the images from the `drawable` folders, if so you wish. Obviously, not by using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to store the image name in database (i.e. "image1" in your example). Then later get the identifier for it using image name as below:

```
int imageId=context.getResources().getIdentifier("imageName","mipmap",context.getPackageName());
```

Now, you can use this **imageId** for setting image to image view.

```
imgview.setImageRessource(imageId);
```